# Dynamic css using dotless

Tags: css, less, dotless

I want to use Less to compile my CSS server-side using dotless. My issue is that I want to change the variable from the server side which is coming from the database, for example I have a header; it's color property is changed by the variable name called `@foo`. Is it possible to change `@foo` from the server side? Assign the value that is stored in data base

```
#header {
  color: @foo;
}
```

If yes, then how?

Answer (score 2):

If you are referencing your less file directly in your page you can pass parameters via a querystring.  You could pass your database value to the less file this way.

**Example**

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.less?foo=red" />
```

**Outputs**

```
#header {
    color: red;
}
```